# Javascript get a 100 percentage regardless of the total number

Tags: javascript

I have a progress bar which needs to be a 100 percent , Now I was thinking about what formula can we use so we can always end up getting 100 ?. For example if the user inputs 1 then we will multiply that by 100 so we can 100 but what if the user input 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 ,5 ,6 ,7 8 ,9  what formulat we will use to still get 100. The limit is number 10.

Comment: just take `100`, or do you want to take the needed factor?

Comment: basic math leads us to `(current / total) * 100 = percentage`. What's the issue?

Comment: Would `1`, `2`, `3` etc. all give 100? Or some proportion of 100?

Comment: There is misunderstanding here.

Comment: Multiply by `100 / input`.

Comment: In fact you have an input X and want Y such as X * Y = 100 ?

Comment: `myNumber + (100 - myNumber)`

Comment: How can we get a total for 100 based on a value which is from 1 - 10 . For example input is 1 so ill multiply it to 100 then i got 100, Now another example 2 then ill multiple it by 50 so will get 100 and so on..

Comment: @Weedoze: `myNumber + (100 - myNumber)` somehow doesn't seem correct ;)

Comment: I mean the formula to that.

Comment: Can you provide sample input with the expected output? I have trouble following which number should result in what percentage.

Comment: userInput * (100/userInput) = 100, as Barmar said

Comment: `input * (100 / input)` ?

Comment: 1 * 100 = 100  , 2 * 50 = 100 , 3 * 30 + 10 = 100 and so on ..

Comment: We're missing a whole lot of context here. **Why** do you want to do this. If you want to get `100` regardless of the input then just return `100`. `const keepIt100 = input => 100;` `keepIt100(2)` returned `100`.

Comment: @iArcadia that means that `input` is irrelevant in the formula and you should (mathematically) end up with `100`. Floating point arithmetic might lead to different results in programming, though.

Comment: @VLAZ He wants a result equals to 100 so... But you have the point for your last sentence.

Comment: It's for a loading bar, I guess he doesn't want a bar going from 0 to 100, but something increasing and linear which ends up to 100

Comment: @AntoineGautrain then the formula to get 100 is irrelevant, it's as I initially thought - the formula to get a percentage out of the whole.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Uznlsro

Comment: Please check the image , as you can see there are 10 items one is checked and that is 10 percent , now what i really mean , is what if there were only 1 item and it is checked so the value of that item whould be 100 , and what if there are 3 items ? and so on

Comment: @AdamKaylin What happened if we check a second checkbox? We increase to 20%??  Is this your issue?

Comment: @AdamKaylin again, `current / total * 100` So with 1 checked and 3 total, you get `1 / 3 * 100 = 33.3` (rounded). It's basic maths.

Answer (score 0):

Strange request but as mentioned in the comments

`100 / n * n` will always be `100`

(keep in mind you will sometimes see `99,999999...` but due to mathematical definitions this is still 100

---

You can try it out here:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    n: 5
  },
  computed: {
    always100() {
      return (100 / this.n) * this.n;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="n" />
  <p> {{ always100 }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "*`100 / n * n` will always be `100`*" to be precise, not always - `100 / 0.3 * 0.3` results in `100.00000000000001`. And the *seemingly* equivalent formula `n * n / 100` can fail with `n = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` resulting in `8.112963841460667e+29`. Still you're correct talking about mathematics and logic, as I doubt the intention here is to exploit limitations with numeric representations in programming.

Comment: "_`100 / n * n` will always be `100`_". But `100` will also always be `100`. So why add a redundant calculation instead of returning `100`?

Comment: @Ivar why ask me?
I didnt request this strange calculation

Comment: Because you provided the answer. In cases like these it's better to wait for OP to clarify, because it simply doesn't make sense, nor will it help anyone in the future. And as it turns out, [it's indeed not what OP had in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276353/javascript-get-a-100-percentage-regardless-of-the-total-number/55276534?noredirect=1#comment97283237_55276353).